# Angular 4 and Phonegap

Tags: angular, cordova, phonegap

I am using Angular 4 with phonegap 7.1.1. It works fine on iOS but if I try using the app on android it stucks after some time with no errors. Have no idea why this happens. Android target version is 5.0.0 . This is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.name.text" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Name</name>
    <description>
        name
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        name
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="20" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-manifest/application/@android:hardwareAccelerated" value="true" />
        <preference name="android-manifest/@android:hardwareAccelerated" value="true" />
    </platform>
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <allow-intent href="data:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="^5.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="^1.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="^1.3.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^4.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^2.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" spec="^1.0.8" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.7.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^1.3.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" spec="^2.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" spec="^1.2.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^2.4.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="^2.3.0">
        <variable name="XWALK_VERSION" value="23+" />
        <variable name="XWALK_LITEVERSION" value="xwalk_core_library_canary:17+" />
        <variable name="XWALK_COMMANDLINE" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
        <variable name="XWALK_MODE" value="embedded" />
        <variable name="XWALK_MULTIPLEAPK" value="true" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="^1.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-pdf-generator" spec="^1.9.3" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Are there any android logcat logs about your application or something? I'm assuming that you don't see any errors in js console.

Comment: @ Dawid Paluchowski  Yeah, I am using angular router for navigation but whenever I click on a link there is an error in logcat logs wich says something like "couldn't get file://name-of-the-component"

Comment: Well it look like there is some problem with routing or application file package. Check angular routing for some name typos in the name of the component which is prompted in logcat error.